# Замена значений в столбцах датафрейма

Tags: dataframe, r

У меня есть датафрейм, состоящий из нескольких столбцов, например, такой:

```
t <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
v1 <- c(5, 5, 5, 6, 7, 5, 4, 3, 1, 2)
v2 <- c(1, 2, 6, 7, 8, 5, 3, 9, 1, 4)
v3 <- c(6, 4, 3, 2, 8, 4, 3, 1, 2, 4)
dt <- data.frame(t, v1, v2, v3)
```

Я хочу изменить значения в столбцах `v1`, `v2`, `v3` по условию из столбца `t`. Например, заменить нулями все значения, для которых `3 < t < 7`. Сейчас я это делаю так:

```
dt[dt$t > 3 & dt$t < 7,]$v1 <- 0
dt[dt$t > 3 & dt$t < 7,]$v2 <- 0
dt[dt$t > 3 & dt$t < 7,]$v3 <- 0
```

Однако, если столбцов будет много, то код получается довольно громоздкий. А если сделать так

```
dt[dt$t > 3 & dt$t < 7,]<- 0
```

то меняются значения во всех столбцах. Мне же нужно, чтобы значения в столбце `t` остались неизменными. Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

и строки и столбцы фрейма данных можно отбирать как логическим вектором (`dt$t > 3`, `dt$t < 7` и т.п.), так и числовым (`c(1)`, `2`, `c(2, 3)` и т.п.):

```
фрейм[вектор.строк, вектор.столбцов] <- значение
```

в случае логического вектора отбор строк/столбцов можно инвертировать логическим «не».

а в случае числового вектора отбор можно инвертировать, поменяв знак (на «минус»). например, если вам надо исключить первый столбец, укажите в качестве индекса столбцов вектор, содержащий лишь `-1` (альтернативные варианты записи: `-c(1)`, `c(-1)`):

```
фрейм[вектор.строк, -1] <- значение
```